# input of type file is not displayed on the screen

Tags: php, html

I have created a that is supposed to have an input of type file and a submit button for uploading that file. My problem is that myfile is not displayed in the web browser but the submit button. Can you please help me to find the misstake.

```
echo "<form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'> 
        <imput type='file' name='myfile'/>
        <input type='submit' value='Ladda upp'/>
        </form>";
```

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/ would have picked up that mistake. Please do basic automated QA before asking for help from other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pair of extra eyes could help:

```
<imput type='file' name='myfile'/>
  ^
```

Aside from that, you could input HTML directly in your code, like so:

```
<?php

    // some code ...

?>

<form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'> 
<input type='file' name='myfile'/>
<input type='submit' value='Ladda upp'/>
</form>
```

It's always better to separate your HTML from the actual code wherever possible.

Comment: Yes. What a silly misstake. I am not allowed to accept your answer yet but I will. Thank you.

Comment: @FilipEriksson: yeah, it happens. It's a good idea to check for any typos in your code before posting to SO. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Html never invented `<imput>` tag.
it is

```
<input ='file' name='myfile'/>
  ^
  See see see
```